# How to handle dynamic URLs while crawling online stores?

Tags: python, url, dynamic

I am crawling online stores for price comparison. Mot of the stores are using dynamic URLs heavily. This is causing my crawler to spend lot of time on every online stores. Even though most of them have only 5-6k unique products, they have unique URLs >= 300k. Any idea how to get around this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you parsing some product pages, usually these URLs have some kind of product id.

Find the pattern to extract product id from URLs, and use it to filter already visited URLs.

Comment: What I am trying to is - find all the products for an online store. I know how to identify the product page. Problem is how do I know that I have identified all the products until I visit all the URLs as they may contain a link to product. Also I am not visiting already crawled url

Comment: I had a similar issue with Amazon. Many times category url has additional argument called 'query' (or similar), which is always different. I didn't try to deal with it on category pages. But you can try to manually clean these urls and store them somewhere, and write your own duplicate middleware to use your stored urls. Or you can leave it as it is (as i did) and only use the product id: request a product id page only if product id (which you extract from url) is not stored in the db (or memory) as already extracted.

Comment: Thanks, Thats exactly the problem I am facing. I will have to think  of some other idea. Thanks for sharing your experience!